# syntax errors about triggers in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my Table schema created as per the question :

```
INSERT INTO sells(bar, beer, price) VALUES ('Sue''s Bar', 'Miller', 2.75);

INSERT INTO sells(bar, beer, price) VALUES ('Tom''s Bar', 'Miller', 2.5);

INSERT INTO sells(bar, beer, price) VALUES ('Cox', 'Miller', 2.75);

INSERT INTO beers(name, manf, cost) VALUES ('Winterbrew', 'Pete''s', 2.1);

INSERT INTO beers(name, manf, cost) VALUES ('Bud Lite', 'Anheuser-Busch', 2.2);

INSERT INTO beers(name, manf, cost) VALUES ('Bud', 'Anheuser-Busch', 2.3);
```

Here is the question: 
b. Please write a trigger, named hw06b, in Oracle to change beer’s prices the same ratio as
the beer’s cost changed. For example, if beer’s cost is changed to $2.2 from $2.0, then
the prices of this beer in every bar should add 10%.

And THIS IS my code.

```
CREATE TRIGGER hw06b AFTER UPDATE OF price ON sells  
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    ratio real;    
begin    
    ratio = (:new.cost - :old.cost)/ :old.cost;    
    insert into sells(price) values (:old.cost*(1+ratio));    
end;
```

It looks syntactically correct, however the ORACLE say there is a complication error to create the trigger. I can't figure out why.  I am stumped on this.

[image]

Comment: "Encountered `=` when expecting `:=`". Wow, the error message says it right there. All you have to do is read the error text.

Comment: You do know that `ratio = (:new.cost - :old.cost)/ :old.cost` combined with `:old.cost*(1+ratio)` is the same as `:new.cost`, right? That's a lot of math just to take the `:new.cost` value, obscuring what you're doing.

Comment: sorry I am a newbie : (, this is my first time to use plussql, but thank you a lot. I've fixed the error.

Comment: @yuchenJoe apart from the question, please try to `code` the names wherever you meet. For your case, instead of 'Miller', 'Winterbrew', 'Bud Lite' ... etc. use 1, 2 , 3 ... respectively and hold this info in a `look-up` table( here `beers`, instead of name hold numbers in this table ), which's binded with `foreign - primary key relationship` with `sells` table.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to *insert* a new row into the table the trigger is defined on.  I think you just want to update a value in the row being updated.

For that, use a *before* update trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER hw06b BEFORE UPDATE OF price ON sells  
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    ratio real;    
BEGIN    
    ratio := (:new.cost - :old.cost)/ :old.cost;
    :new.price := :old.cost * (1 + ratio);  
END;
```

Comment: And since `:old.cost * (1 + ratio)  =  :old.cost * (1 + (:new.cost - :old.cost) / :old.cost)  =  :old.cost + (:new.cost - :old.cost)  =  :new.cost`, it really is just `:new.price := :new.cost;` --- Also, you didn't explain the actual error in the question, i.e. that `=` should be `:=`.

Comment: I use the above statements, but I still get bad bind errors. The price come from sells, and cost come from beers. They come from two different tables. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

From [comment to other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47128028/syntax-errors-about-triggers-in-oracle?noredirect=1#comment81209327_47128110):

> The `price` come from `sells`, and `cost` come from `beers`. They come from two different tables.

Your trigger only mentions `sells`. There is no reference to `beers` anywhere, and since the trigger table is `sells`, references like `:old.cost` doesn't work, because the `sells` table doesn't have such a column.

Since your code calculates the ratio of a changed `cost` value and that column exists in the `beers` table, I think you meant to create the trigger on `cost ON beers`, not `price ON sells`.

Since there is no obvious relationship between `sells` and `beers`, it's unclear exactly what `sells` record should be updated by the trigger.

It does seem very unlikely that you want to insert a record into `sells` with null values for `bar` and `beer`, which is what your current insert statement is doing.